# Google Cloud Storage is giving me Authorization code 401 Invalid Credentials when trying to connect

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-cloud-speech

1. I have completed the guides [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)
2. Also i have completed [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart) guides as well (as I want to use both Storage and Speech)

Now i have `gcloud` and it is working in the terminal i also tried executing this command from the shell:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
    -d @sync-request.json
```

And it is working as I am getting:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.9840146
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i try to put some code. For example this one:

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Imports the Google Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function auth_cloud_implicit($projectId)
{
    $config = [
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ];

    # If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the
    # client library will look for credentials in the environment.
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'somenumbersandletters';

auth_cloud_implicit($projectId);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } } in /var/www/speech/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php on line 263
```

So my question is what i am doing wrong and why this code is not working? I have do the same code on other computer and it is working fine, i do not get it why it is not working over this computer the same way? Any suggestions will be more then welcome!

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine with gcloud installed? For Application Default Credentials to work, make sure you've acquired credentials at some point: `gcloud auth application-default login`.

Comment: well i just did that, it reacted a new json file and i typed this command `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"` to the json file that i just created, but it is giving me the same error :(

Comment: That's odd. Maybe something up with your environment variables? Try explicitly setting the `keyFilePath`, and see if that works. If so, probably something about your environment variable reaching your app: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-php

Comment: which `keyFilePath` do you mean, the Service Account json key? Is that the key? Inside this key there is information such as `type
project_id
private_key_id
private_key
client_email
client_id
auth_uri
token_uri
auth_provider_x509_cert_url
client_x509_cert_url`

Comment: I mean `new StorageClient($config = [ 'keyFilePath' => $SYSTEM_PATH_TO_YOUR_JSON_FILE, 'projectId' => $projectId ])`.

Comment: yes, i tried that and then i get other error `code": 403, "message": "starting-account-dxnzeigf8w62@speechdemo-**.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 545722916**1.` which email is the service account ID and i guess it is saying that this account dont have permission, but i was thinking i have connected the app to my account which is dimitar.k****@gmail.com. So i dont know how to give permissions to this service account/email right now?

Comment: i saw one more thing.... why in the developer computer i see only one account (my own account) when i run `gcloud init` and on the production computer i see 2 accounts (my account and the service account i have mentioned above)!? i dont get that from my developer computer `Choose the account you would like to use to perform operations for 
this configuration:
 [1] dimitar.****@gmail.com
 [2] Log in with a new account
`

Comment: the strenges thing is that on the developer computer is working with the same code, same json and same dependencies from composer and same versions a course, the only difference i as able to saw is when i init the gcloud i see 2 accounts in the production server and only 1 in the developer

Comment: The service account does not have your permissions. It has only its own permissions. You'll need to grant the account starting-account-dxnzeigf8w62@etc explicit permission to use the bucket (or give it equivalent project-wide access), and your production computer is likely somewhere in the Google cloud, where authenticating as a service account can happen automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022**

```
$config = [
    'credentials' => [PATH-TO-JSON-FILE],
];

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient($config);
```

**UPDATE 2018**

```
use Google\Auth\Credentials\GCECredentials;

$gceCredentials = new GCECredentials();
$config = [
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'credentialsFetcher' => $gceCredentials,
];
```

What i have noticed is that when you want to instantiate a Google Service you just have to put the JSON file inside the array and it should work. For example if you want to instantiate Google Speech Client simply do this:

```
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'keyFilePath' => 'path/to/file.json',
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
]);
```

and if you want Google Storage Client, then simply:

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
   'projectId' => $projectId,
   'keyFilePath' => 'path/to/file.json',   
])
```

**If that doesn't help then try also**

Go to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) and use this code for connection to the bucket:

```
function auth_cloud_explicit($projectId, $serviceAccountPath)
{
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    $config = [
        'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ];
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}
```

and also going to [Google Cloud Platform / IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/) and adding the service account that the code was giving an error that this account does not have an access to the bucket. Now everything is working fine! Thanks to @brandon-yarbrough for the help

If none of the above works for you just try and setup the environment  inside your file using this code:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
```

And this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;       
 $storage = new StorageClient([
        'keyFilePath' => 'path/key.json',
        'projectId' => 'you_projectid'
    ]);
    $bucket = $storage->bucket('namebucket');
    $bucket->upload(
        fopen('data/demo.txt', 'r')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same all of the sudden trying to access one of my GCP storage buckets (specifically I was getting `401 Invalid Credentials` when trying to use `gsutil` to transfer files from one of my buckets).

I was finally able to get around by simply DELETING the bucket, creating a new one, then re-uploading my folder, which worked on first go.